# C# How do I use a variable outside of a loop that changes from string to int inside the loop?

Tags: c#, for-loop, tryparse

The code:

```
string[] numbers = new string[2];
for (int i = 0; i < numbers.Length; i++)
{
    numbers[i] = Console.ReadLine();
    if (int.TryParse(numbers[i], out int numberTry) && i == 0)
        Console.WriteLine("That would be a number yes.");

    else if (int.TryParse(numbers[i], out numberTry))
        Console.WriteLine("Lovely work! That is indeed two numbers!");

    else
    {
        Console.Clear();
        Console.WriteLine("That's not a number. I am dissapointed.");
        Console.ReadKey();
        Environment.Exit(0);
    }
}
```

My problem here is that I can't use numbers[] outside of the loop as an int because it chancges from a string to an int inside of the loop. I need to be able to send it with a method as an int to perform a operation on numbers[0] and numbers[1].
Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can create another array of ints that you populate inside your loop.

Comment: Thanks for the idea!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Could you try this. It should work.

```
    int[] numbers = new int[2];
    for (int i = 0; i < numbers.Length; i++)
    {
        var number = Console.ReadLine();
        if (int.TryParse(number, out int numberTry) && i == 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("That would be a number yes.");
            numbers[i] = numberTry;
        }
        else if (int.TryParse(number, out numberTry))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Lovely work! That is indeed two numbers!");
            numbers[i] = numberTry;
        }
        else
        {
            Console.Clear();
            Console.WriteLine("That's not a number. I am dissapointed.");
            Console.ReadKey();
            Environment.Exit(0);
        }
    }

    Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: That did seem to work yes! Cheers! Now if you don't mind, what did you do exactly as I can't seem to find any other differences then the "numbers[i] = numberTry".

Comment: @Hagwill I changed the string[] array to int[] array. then i read your value from console in number variable. I add that value to numbers[] array inside condition. If it is correct, could you click the upvote ? have good work.

Comment: Ah okay thank you for the explantion. I did but I have 8 reputation so you can't see it. Good luck with your future work as well!